# Simple IF EXISTS in TRIGGER fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, exists

I've created a simple TRIGGER:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SprawdzZajetosc] ON [dbo].[Wypozyczenia]
FOR insert, update
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Wypozyczenia)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Wybrany pojazd został już wypożyczony w wybranym przedziale czasu.', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
```

I can't understand why 'if' is returning me `TRUE` even if table 'Wypozyczenia' is empty? It doesn't matter what 'Wypozyczenia' contains - it always returns me `TRUE`.

I tried with `count(*)` it always returns me a value > 0.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure of this, but it sounds logical to me - The trigger is an insert/update trigger. As soon as something is being inserted, the trigger is triggered and the condition is TRUE. Since there is a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION fired, the inserted row is then rolled back and hence you get an empty table. What are you actually trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the reasons why you're doing this, the cause for `IF EXISTS()` to be always `TRUE` in your case is **very simple** it's because you're using an `AFTER` or `FOR` trigger.

> [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
>   AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired **only** when **all operations**
>   specified in the triggering SQL statement **have executed successfully**.
>   All referential cascade actions and constraint checks also must
>   succeed before this trigger fires.

Meaning the row(s) you're trying to insert are already in the table. It's just a transaction has not been committed yet.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b421c)** demo

---

Your `IF EXISTS()` check might've worked only in `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger but then you should've take into consideration that triggers in SQL Server are statement based. Meaning it fires once per statement and you can insert more than one row in one statement.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47382/1)** demo

---

As far as `FOR UPDATE` clause goes in your trigger definition it doesn't make any sense at all. If you're updating something it should be in the table. Thus table is not empty.